# Error: "Object DOMDocument should be created." When add/edit product attributes

Tags: magento2, magento-ce

Whenever I edit or add a product attribute, I receive a error with the header

"There has been an error processing your request"

and body saying

```
"Object DOMDocument should be created."

The error log reads :
" a:4:{i:0;s:37:"Object DOMDocument should be created.";i:1;s:10125:"#0 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/Reader.php(95): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger->getDom()
#1 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(261): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Reader->read()
#2 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(169): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepare('form_schedule_b...')
#3 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(139): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepareData('form_schedule_b...')
#4 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(125): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('form_schedule_b...', NULL, Array)
#5 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'form_schedule_b...', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#6 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#7 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#8 /home/puffpackage/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#9 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#10 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#11 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#12 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(166): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#13 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(475): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
#14 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(433): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getElementAttribute('body', 'class')
#15 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute.php(90): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->addBodyClass('attribute-popup')
#16 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Edit.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute->createActionPage(Object(Magento\Framework\Phrase))
#17 /home/puffpackage/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Edit/Interceptor.php(25): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit->execute()
#18 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Interceptor->execute()
#19 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute.php(72): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 [internal function]: Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#23 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#24 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#25 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#28 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Interceptor), Array, 'designLoader')
#29 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/Design.php(39): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\Design->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#32 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#33 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#36 /home/puffpackage/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Edit/Interceptor.php(40): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#37 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#40 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#41 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#42 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#43 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#44 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#45 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCookieVali...')
#46 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Plugin/StoreCookie.php(78): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#47 [internal function]: Magento\Store\Model\Plugin\StoreCookie->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#48 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#49 /home/puffpackage/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#50 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#51 /home/puffpackage/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#52 /home/puffpackage/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#53 {main}";s:3:"url";s:244:"/puffmin/catalog/product_attribute/new/store/0/product_tab/variations/popup/1/key/5c2a345ed1b7894fdb9bca01f9daba0c242a4451e6b492633a2d909675076f05/?attribute%5Bis_global%5D=1&attribute%5Bfrontend_input%5D=select&set=4&attribute[frontend_label]=";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";} "
```

Comment: Can you be more specific how you tried this? via admin or editing xml files?

Comment: From the admin page, when editing a product it has configurable which include the products attribute, I've also tried editing it from the attributes section itself and it had the same error.

Comment: you should check var/log/system.log in last code.

Comment: The error log reads: [2015-12-16 06:40:32] main.CRITICAL: Can't create directory /home/puffpackage/public_html/var/generation/Magento
/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Config/Reader/. [] []

Comment: Magento 2.0 CE if it helps..

Comment: Please check the var/log/system.log for more information. Even an undefined variable will cause this error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like `var/generation` is not writable. Make sure to set [proper file system ownership and permissions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/file-system-perms.html): `var`, `app/etc` and `pub/static` should be writable by web server.

Comment: It was var/composer & symfony which had the wrong owner.
I'm not sure why this ownership was wrong or why'd it'd cause this problem,
but thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 18):

Another possible reason for the `Object DOMDocument should be created.` error is the unaccessible `ui_component/your_listing.xml` file under the `view/adminhtml/` folder when you want to create an Adminhtml Grid and you declare it under the `view/adminhtml/layout/your_handle_index.xml` as this:

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="your_listing"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: Yep, indeed, I had this problem. Now I'm moving on to the next error :). Multumesc!

Comment: In my case, I misspelled the directory of  `view/adminhtml/`

Comment: this helps alot in my case i have some extra code in vendor/magento/framework/view/element/UiComponentFactory.php related to UI which was not supposed to be there

Answer (score 10):

Another possible reason for this error is if your class folders don't have proper capitalization (i.e. are lowercase).

**var/log/system.log:**

```
[2016-02-26 21:19:51] main.CRITICAL: Class Example\Myclass\Block\ShopCategory does not exist [] []
[2016-02-26 21:19:51] main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Example\Myclass\Block\ShopCategory [] []
```

For example, if the namespace folder is "example" rather than "Example" it will work just fine on Windows and most Mac installations, but will fail with the "Object DOMDocument should be created." error on Linux, as Linux uses a case-sensitive filesystem.

Comment: Thx for the hint to look into system.log. For me was a simple php notice `Notice: Undefined index: regalo_mittente in /app/code/Custom/Backend/Helper/Data.php on line 50`

Comment: This should be the first thing to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Recently during a module development I got the same kind of error. In my case I found out the real error which was:

> Circular dependency: Vendor\Module\Helper\Data depends on Vendor\Module\Helper\Bot and vice versa.

I removed this dependency from the `__construct` method of my helpers (refactored them using one parent class) and error is gone. So I'll recommend you to check circular dependencies in your code.

Another kind of error: Fatal Error during render the component, caused by call to the not existing class from 3rd party module.

**As I understand this type of error is thrown when the Fatal Error occurs during render of the component and has nothing common with an Object DOM Document.**

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have migrated your data from Magento 1 to Magento 2, and if you are getting this error on a specific page, then follow below steps:

If you are getting this error in specific **product view page**, **Category page** or any cms page then goto that product/category or CMS page edit section and goto **Design** section and within **layout update XML**  if any block is added then comment that XML code or remove it and clear your cache and check on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this also.. checking var/log/system.log shows open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/etc/pki/tls/certs)

removing the open_basedir restriction fixed the problem