# Magento 2: Custom block doesn't show on the cart page

Tags: magento2, cart, custom-block

**Namespace/Modulename/Block/donation.php**

```
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block;

class Productpoint extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


}
```

**Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/web/templates/checkout/cart/donation.phtml**

```
<span><?php echo 'Eureka'; ?></span>
```

**Rewrite checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Productpoint" before="-" template="Namespace_Modulename::checkout/cart/productpoint.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

The block is not loading on cart page. How do I call my custom block on cart page?

Comment: How about your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your phtml is wrong path, remove `web` folder, it should be: `Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/checkout/cart/donation.phtml`

Second, Your block is wrong name: `Namespace/Modulename/Block/donation.php` => `Namespace/Modulename/Block/Productpoint.php`

Third, you can add your block to the containers such items and no items or additional block info. Your template will be rendered automatically.

And your `template="Namespace_Modulename::checkout/cart/productpoint.phtml` should be `checkout/cart/donation.phtml`.

***checkout_cart_index.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="with-items">
            <block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Productpoint" name="custom.block" before="-" 
              template="Namespace_Modulename::checkout/cart/donation.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="no-items">
            <block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Productpoint" name="custom.block" before="-" 
              template="Namespace_Modulename::checkout/cart/donation.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceBlock name="additional.product.info">
            <block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Productpoint" name="custom.block" before="-" 
              template="Namespace_Modulename::checkout/cart/donation.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: There has been an error processing your request Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.a:4:{i:0;s:37:"Object DOMDocument should be created.";i:1;s:12986:"#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\m202s\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Reader.php(95): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger->getDom()
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\m202s\vendor\magento\module-ui\Model\Manager.php(261): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\m202s\vendor\magento\module-ui\Model\Manager.php(169): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepare('additional.prod...')

Comment: @parasarora1303 try this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93783/error-object-domdocument-should-be-created-when-add-edit-product-attributes

Comment: I am currently working on local magento on windows and it is having proper permissions . even I had remove pub/static inner folder and also all folder of var and run php bin/setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Your template `checkout/cart/productpoint.phtml` or `checkout/cart/donation.phtml`? I have just updated my answer.

Comment: my template is productpoint.phtml

Comment: `productpoint.phtml ` is existing?

Comment: yes it is at the location view\frontend\templates\checkout\cart\productpoint.phtml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48232/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-parasarora1303).

Answer (score 1):

You have put your phtml file at wrong place,Follow Below path

**Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/checkout/cart/donation.phtml**
After doing so clear your cache and run static content deploy. It should work.