# Object DOMDocument should be created error in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I created a credit card form under custom payment method  by following 
[this link](https://webkul.com/blog/add-cc-form-custom-payment-method-magento2/)

I'm getting a  **sytem.log error**

```
[2019-02-06 06:22:10] main.CRITICAL: Class VendorName\Worldpaydirect\Model\          
Source does not exist [] []
```

> **di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
     <arguments>
        <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="vendorname_worldpaydirect_configprovider" xsi:type="object">VendorName\Worldpaydirect\Model\WorldpaydirectConfigProvider</item>
        </argument>
     </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> VendorName/Worldpaydirect/Model/WorldpaydirectConfigProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\Worldpaydirect\Model;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Source;
class WorldpaydirectConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
public function __construct(\Magento\Payment\Model\CcConfig $ccConfig,
        Source $assetSource)
{
$this->ccConfig = $ccConfig;
$this->assetSource = $assetSource;
}
protected $_methodCode = 'worldpaydirect';
public function getConfig()
{
return [
'payment' => [
'worldpaydirect' => [
'availableTypes' => [$this->_methodCode => $this->ccConfig->etCcAvailableTypes()],
'months' => [$this->_methodCode => $this->ccConfig->getCcMonths()],
'years' => [$this->_methodCode => $this->ccConfig->getCcYears()],
'hasVerification' => $this->ccConfig->hasVerification(),
]
]
];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `var/generation` is not writable here.

Magento 2 generates classes inside `var/generation` directory. So, if there is folder permission issue or folder owner issue with that directory then the class cannot be generated and you get such error.

When you clear `var/generation` directory and set appropriate permission to it then this error should be solved.

you have to remove `rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/*`

after run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: i did but its show VendorName\Worldpaydirect\Model\        Source does not exist  @rakesh

Comment: @divyasekar i have updated my answer you can remove and after run above command this sequence

Comment: its not working

Comment: @divyasekar this problem solve i have say but you can check also here 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/94458/68695